Is a grammar in a EBNF form equivalent to one in a Pydantic model form?
Python Pydantic models and EBNF (context free grammar) are two competing ways to have a LLM generate structured, sensible output.
Although the links reference the Outlines library, I am also curious if anyone has a general explanation of whether one functionally subsumes the other, or if they are equivalent, ignoring stylistic issues.
